# Data Migration from MS Dynamics CRM 4.0 to MS Dynamics CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-4

How we can import data [data migration ] from CRM 4.0 to CRM 2011 ? Do we have any Data Import Wizard [ Tool ] to Import data from 4.0 to 2011 . If yes could you please provide me the url.

And also can we import data using CRM webservices?

Please give me you ideas and suggestions on this.

Thanks in Advance

Prajosh

Comment: Have you read the migration guide Microsoft makes available? What in particular does it not cover? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd362093.aspx

Comment: @ta.speot.is this question is about Dynamics _CRM_, not Dynamics _AX_

Answer (score 1):

There's two questions here, so two answers:

1) You can import data using CRM Webservices, and they are pretty well documented throughout MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334357.aspx

2) If you have a current CRM 4.0 installation that you want to "upgrade" to CRM 2011, it is a supported upgrade. Your upgrade options are documented in a few places - try the CRM 2011 Deployment guide, or this Technet article: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg554717.aspx - I have used and prefer the "new instance of SQL server" method as it seems safest and easiest to roll-back. I highly recommend avoiding the in-place upgrade - do **not** try to import your live CRM 4 database, into CRM 2011 as it is a one-way operation and the database will stop working in CRM 4.0!

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solutions for the error,which I had posted.

given below is the solution :-

[http://weblogs.asp.net/pabloperalta/archive/2010/11/01/step-by-step-installing-crm-2011-on-premise-and-migrating-from-dynamics-crm-4-0-32-bits-on-premise.asp](http://weblogs.asp.net/pabloperalta/archive/2010/11/01/step-by-step-installing-crm-2011-on-premise-and-migrating-from-dynamics-crm-4-0-32-bits-on-premise.aspx)

xThanks & Regards

prajosh